# How can I build JavaScript instruction dynamically from parameters?

Tags: javascript

I want to construct javascript instruction dynamically

the original instruction is :

```
 var chou = eval('(' + returnResult + ')').attribute;
```

I want to pass the attribute as variable is it possible?

I have tried :

```
 var chou = eval('(' + returnResult + ')').eval(baseentity);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What are returnResult/baseentity?

Comment: Maybe `var chou = eval('(' + returnResult + ').'+baseentity);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be optimistic and assume that `returnResult` is JSON.

Then you can do

```
var chou = JSON.parse(returnResult)[baseentity];
```

If it's not exactly JSON but you trust the source enough to use eval, then you could do

```
var chou = eval('(' + returnResult + ')')[baseentity];
```

Comment: Note: `JSON.parse` is not supported by IE <= 7.

Comment: If support of IE7 is needed, some shims can be found at http://json.org and many libraries (for example jQuery) have one too.

Comment: That will invoke a method on the object created by JSON.parse, not pass baseentity as a variable to the 'javascript instruction' he created dynamically. I don't think this is what he's asking for?

Comment: @mattmanser I think you should read the question again, especially the part about the "attribute".